# Is there a way to schedule a flow to run three times in a day?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I wrote an Apex class and I have used that class in Schedule-Triggered Flow, and I want to schedule it to run thrice a day. While searching about I found that I have to create a Schedule-Triggered Flow and clone it two times but that will override my existing data and I don't want that to happen.

So I just wanted to know is there any way to automate the flow three times a day or any other ways to do it?

Comment: Is your flow only calling your Apex Class? or there are other logic being performed?

Comment: how could running three flows at different times of the day overwrite your data?

Comment: Use Apex's System.schedule method to schedule the class at three different times. You'll need to write three different cron expressions for each desired time.

Comment: If you need to schedule the entire flow to run, you can't use System.schedule() method.  But as cropredy says, why do you think your flow will overwrite your data?  Please [edit] your post to clarify and describe what your flow does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but that will override my existing data

No, it won't. With that approach you'll have three scheduled flows running the same logic at different times. You really don't need a class that implements the Schedulable interface, you only need the three flows to do what they must at three different scheduled times (one at each time). To do this you might want to have a sub-flow with the logic you want to run, and then three flows calling that sub-flow.

There are more complicated ways to approach this with Apex and flows, but they seem to be over-complicated for your scenario, in my opinion. You could have a scheduled Apex class that calls the flow, or write the entire logic in Apex and have that be on a schedulable class. Then all you need to do is use the `System.schedule` method three times, with a different CRON expression each time, scheduling that class.

Comment: Thank you very much Renato, Schedulable class helped me a lot. Much appreciated